# who to used Dismissible to delete the task from a database, using flutter and sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite, dismissible

All!

I want to delete the task by using a Dismissible widget.

I try the following

```
onDismissed: (direction)  {
   DatabaseHelper.instance.deleteTask(task.id);
   _updateTaskList();
},
```

and it works but the animation looks wrong as if the dismissed child reappear for a second and then disappears.

I think what is happening is that the `deleteTask` has a delay and the `_updateTaskList` it's running almost at the same time.

this are my methods:

```
  Future<int> deleteTask(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    final int result = await db.delete(
      tasksTable,
      where: '$colId = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
    return result;
  }
}


  _updateTaskList() {
    setState(() {
      _taskList = DatabaseHelper.instance.getTaskList();
    });
  }



 Future<List<Task>> getTaskList() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> taskMapList = await getTaskMapList();
    final List<Task> taskList = [];
    taskMapList.forEach((taskMap) {
      taskList.add(Task.fromMap(taskMap));
    });
    return taskList;
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to use setState when using the dismissible widget. You just need to make sure the item is no longer in List variable being used in the ListView.

Comment: @JoãoSoares that works, but the next time I used `setState` in the same screen  the task I dismissed reappear for a second

Comment: After you removed it from the List? You don't just remove it from the db, you have to remove it from your _taskList variable. If you wait for the DB query to reflect on your _taskList, then you run the risk of having the item appear temporarily.